# Split string after each number

Tags: php, regex, split, text-extraction, preg-split

I have a database full of strings that I'd like to split into an array.  Each string contains a list of directions that begin with a letter (U, D, L, R for Up, Down, Left, Right) and a number to tell how far to go in that direction.

Here is an example of one string.

```
$string = "U29R45U2L5D2L16";
```

My desired result:

```
['U29', 'R45', 'U2', 'L5', 'D2', 'L16']
```

I thought I could just loop through the string, but I don't know how to tell if the number is one or more spaces in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to break up the string, splitting on something which looks like a U,L,D or R followed by numbers and using the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` to keep the split text:

```
$string = "U29R45U2L5D2L16";
print_r(preg_split('/([UDLR]\d+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => U29
    [1] => R45
    [2] => U2
    [3] => L5
    [4] => D2
    [5] => L16 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/asaFU)

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression should help you:

```
<?php
$string = "U29R45U2L5D2L16";
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]\d+/", $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this task is about text extraction and not about text validation, you can merely split on the zer-width position after one or more digits.  In other words, match one or more digits, then forget them with `\K` so that they are not consumed while splitting.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eerQg))

```
$string = "U29R45U2L5D2L16";
var_export(
    preg_split(
        '/\d+\K/',
        $string,
        0,
        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'U29',
  1 => 'R45',
  2 => 'U2',
  3 => 'L5',
  4 => 'D2',
  5 => 'L16',
)
```